# Android: Sqlite without SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to use SqliteDatabase without using SQLiteOpenHelper (since I don't have Context while creating the DB).

this is my code:

```
database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("/data/data/com.example.mytest/database/" + DB_NAME,null);
database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
```

Once i'm trying to run `openOrCreateDatabase` I'm getting:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error
>   (code 14): Could not open database

Couldn't find any good reason why it happens...

Thanks.

Comment: In an Android app, there's always a `Context` you can use.

Comment: try a tutorial to get to grips with how Android and sqlite work, I would suggest creating a static method in your activity that returns the activity (context) so you can use the context anywhere you need.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html